# stored procedure does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdminCheck] (@Name nvarchar, @Password int)

AS
Select * from Admin
where AdminName = @Name AND AdminPassword = @Password
Go
```

Above is my `stored procedure` 
I got `Admin` as `AdminName` and `123` as `AdminPassword` in `Admin` table.

When I run it it does not work.

Comment: This is a great place to start: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

```
@Name nvarchar
```

The size of the variable will be 1 by default:
Hence your query will be compared to the first character of `@Name` variable:

Provide proper size for your variable;

```
@Name nvarchar(150)
```

Comment: oh, Thank you.  I  made a little mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You defined your parameter as a NVARCHAR - it means ONE symbol.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdminCheck] (@Name nvarchar, @Password int)
```

So when you call it `AdminCheck('Admin',123)` then `@Name` is actually `'A'` not `'Admin'`

It should be for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdminCheck] (@Name nvarchar(100), @Password int)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call it like this. Please send error message.

`exec [dbo].[AdminCheck] 'Admin',123`